# Why is PostgreSQL very slow when I execute a SELECT query with OR in WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql

The query is like:

```
select count(*)
from test1 as r
WHERE r.testid in (select p.testid from test2 p where p.testname IS NULL)
OR r.testid > (SELECT MAX(p2.testid)FROM test2 p2);
```

but when I rewrite it as UNION it works. What is the problem of this query?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue - PostgreSQL planner cannot use indexes (it's not able to optimize `OR`, when `OR` is used for subselects) and rewriting with `UNION` helps. Last year Tom Lane wrote a patch, but as far as I know, this patch was not merged yet.